# $ x+y = 1 $ and $ \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = 1 $ Solve $ x^3 + y^3 $

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

$x$, $y$ are complex numbers, $x$ and $y$ aren't $0$.

$$ x + y = 1 $$
$$ \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = 1 $$
$$ x^3 + y^3 = ? $$

Thank You!

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the equations?

Comment: $x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$.

Comment: For the complex numbers symbol, put in dollar signs \mathbb{C}.. For the real numbers it's \mathbb{R} etc.@ Siminore I think you mean $(x + y)(x^2 - xy + y^2)$

Comment: @Axel I tried to find `x` and x = $ 1 - \frac{1}{y} $ then $ y^2 = 1 $ and then I have two options $ y = i $ or $ y = -i $ then I haven't continued to work because I have to choose between: A) 1 B) −2 C) −1 D) 8 as solution to $ x^3 + y^3 $

Comment: @Mattos Sorry, my misprint!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349283/if-xy-1-x2y2-2-find-x7y7/1349294#1349294

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Multiplying the second equation by $xy$ we have
$$x+y = 1 \quad \text{and} \quad xy = 1.$$
Any symmetric polynomial in two variables, such as $x^3 + y^3$, can be expressed in terms of $x+y$ and $xy$. Indeed,
$$x^3 + y^3 = (x+y)(x^2 - xy + y^2) = (x+y)((x+y)^2 - 3xy) = 1 \cdot (1 - 3) = -2.$$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}&=1
\\
\frac{x+y}{xy}&=1 
\\
xy&=1
\\
(x+y)^3&=1^3
\\
x^3+y^3+3xy(x+y)&=1
\\
x^3+y^3&=-2
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

A hint:

From the given data it is easy to compute the value of $xy$ as well. This means that you know the values both elementary symmetric functions $\sigma_1:=x+y$ and $\sigma_2:=xy$ of the unknown numbers $x$, $y\in{\mathbb C}$. This will allow you to compute *any* symmetric function of $x$ and $y$, in particular $\pi_3:=x^3+y^3$, without bothering about the values of $x$ and $y$ themselves. Look at Simiore's comment for hints.